# What is the fastest way to rebuild PostgreSQL statistics from zero/scratch with ANALYZE?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-10

I have a PostgreSQL v10 database with a size of about 100GB.

What is the most efficient (fastest) way to rebuild statistics, for example after a major version upgrade?

`ANALYZE` with no parameters updates statistics for then entire database by default — it's painfully slow! This seems like a single process.

Is there any way to parallelize this to speed it up?

Comment: Why must it be fast?

Comment: because queries are terribly slow with missing stats. I had assumed that was obvious

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `vacuumdb` with the same options that `pg_upgrade` suggests:

```
vacuumdb --all --analyze-in-stages
```

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-vacuumdb.html) describes what it does:

> Only calculate statistics for use by the optimizer (no vacuum), like `--analyze-only`. Run several (currently three) stages of analyze
>    with different configuration settings, to produce usable statistics faster.
>
> This option is useful to analyze a database that was newly populated from a restored dump or by `pg_upgrade`. This option will try to
>   create some statistics as fast as possible, to make the database usable, and then produce full statistics in the subsequent stages.

To calculate statistics with several parallel processes, you can use the option `-j` of `vacuumdb`.

Comment: the option I was looking for was -j njobs
--jobs=njobs

Comment: Thanks - I have added that to the answer for posterity.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you know how does this `-j ` under the hood work? For instance, if I have 5 tables, so would it open 5 parallel connections (1 connection per table). 

So this means that if I set this (`-j`) value to 50, it would not have any benefit. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @anasanjaria I didn't read the code, but I guess it would open 50 connections, and 45 of them would sit idle.